# react-native-navigation : navigating with custom header

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a custom header for my stack navigation and I want to navigate to another page when I press on an image. But when I press the image I get an error `undefined is not an object (evaluating _this.props.navigation.navigate')`

In my App.js

```
const ProfileStackNavi = createStackNavigator({
  stackAndTab:{
    screen:ProfileTopTabNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: (
        <MyPageTabBarHeader />
      )
    },
  }
})
```

In my custom header class

```
export default class MyPageTabBarHeader extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
  return(
    <View style={{width:375,height:250, backgroundColor:'white'}}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Register')}>
                    <Image
                    style={{width:23, height:23}}
                    source{require('../Components/Assets/register.png')} />
           </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
    )
  };
}
```

I also tried `<MyPageTabBarHeader navigation={this.props.navigation}/>` but then it gives me the error `undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate')` the same error as previously but without an _ before `this`.

**Edited**

In my App.js I have `createAppContainer`. It looks like this:

```
const StartSwitchNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    one:{
    screen:screenOne,
   },
 {
    two:{
    screen:ProfileStackNavi,
   }
);

const App = createAppContainer(StartSwitchNavigator);

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you included the 'Register' screen in stack

Comment: Have you created App container using `createAppContainer`. Please show your whole code.

Comment: Yes i did it. I edited my code please check :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the navigation isnt being passed properly. try passing it this way :

```
const ProfileStackNavi = createStackNavigator({
  stackAndTab:{
    screen:ProfileTopTabNavigator,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      header: <MyPageTabBarHeader navigation= {navigation} />,
    })
  }
})
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `navigation` prop isn't being passed down, that's normal for a custom header. The prop is usually only passed to screens/views. You simply have to `import withNavigation from 'react-navigation'` in your header component and then `export default withNavigation(MyPageTabBarHeader)` at the bottom of the file instead of when you declare the class.

You will then have access to the `navigation` prop. Here's some [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html#docsNav) about the function.